# Custom Icon not Showing in Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Today I created a custom image for my app and this includes the custom icon on what should it look in Play Store however when we upload it using Admin Console the uploaded apk files has only an icon of Green Background with White Suitcase. Our custom icon does not show. How to fix it? Is there something we forgot?

Answer (score 0):

Tag `<application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` has two attributes for you app icon:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
...
</application>
```

`android:roundIcon` is used on supported devices. Check if you have set these two types of icon

Comment: thnx for the feed back i will try it

Comment: it is included in my manifest and its directories leads me to my custom images but no luck after uploading.